# python - read csv from s3 and identify its encoding info for pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I am making a service to download csv files from s3 bucket.
The bucket contains csv with various encodings (which I may not know before hand), since users are uploading these files.

This is what I am trying:

```
...
obj = s3c.get_object(Bucket= BUCKET_NAME , Key = KEY)
content = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())
df_s3_file = pd.read_csv(content)
...
```

This works fine for utf-8, however for other format it fails (obviously!).

I have found an independent code which can help me identify the encoding of a csv file on a netwrok drive.
It looks like this:

```
...
def find_encoding(fname):
                r_file = open(fname, 'rb').read()
                result = chardet.detect(r_file)
                charenc = result['encoding']
                return charenc

my_encoding = find_encoding(content)
print('detected csv encoding: ',my_encoding)
df_s3_file = pd.read_csv(content, encoding=my_encoding)
...
```

This snippet works absolutely fine for a file on a drive(local), but how do I do this for a file on s3 bucket? Since I am reading the s3 file as **io.BytesIO** object.

I think if I write the file on a drive and then execute the function ***find_encoding***, its going to work, since that function takes csv file as input as opoosed to BytesIO object.

Is there a way to do this without having to download the file on a drive, within memory?

Note: the files size is not very big (<10 mb).

Answer (score 0):

According to their [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) `s3c.get_object(Bucket= BUCKET_NAME , Key = KEY)` will return a `dict` where one of the keys is `ContentEncoding` so I would try:

```
obj = s3c.get_object(Bucket= BUCKET_NAME , Key = KEY)
print(obj["ContentEncoding"])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it seems 'ContentEncoding' is not a part of the response I get from get_object function. I get a KeyError for that. Although I can see it in the doc. Is there way to get that info in response while invoking the get_object function? Infact I am not getting response dictionary as mentioned in the doc at all, there are many missing key values in my response.

Comment: unfortunately content encoding property is only present when explicitly set during upload/write to s3